# Offline map in desktop application

Tags: c#, google-maps, maps, bing-maps

In a win form I am getting location(latitude and longitude) by serial port and want to show this location in map but in offline mode. What is the best way to do this?

I have a device which is installed in vehicle and It sent some data to receiver at xxxK bytes/second out the serial port. And in this data I have lots of information including Latitude and Longitude. I want show that vehicle in map(google map, bing map...).

Comment: Google Earth Pro allows you to import and track your location in real time via a connected GPS device [[link](http://laearth.ohsep.louisiana.gov/intl/en/client/ug_gps.html)]. If you need a custom solution Google Maps API probably has this capability.

Answer (score 2):

You can save your vehicle positions (lat / long) in a simple text file and then open it with Google Earth (offline).

https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148104?hl=en

here is a step-by-step guide on how to do this.

Beware of lat/long format, you may need to work on it depending on what you have